# Is there an `open in browser` option for the `php -S localhost:8080` command?

Tags: php

I'm looking to find an option for the `php -S localhost:8080` command that opens the host you specify in your default browser. If you search the php web server docs there aren't any options listed that do this. So does anyone have any tricks?

Comment: [UPDATE]: You can run `php -S localhost:8080 | open http://localhost:8080` and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in bash, simply run

```
php -S localhost:8080 && xdg-open http://localhost:8080
```

I haven't tested this particular command but similar commands have worked for me in the past.

The answer to this question depends largely on your environment, if this does not work for you, add more detail regarding what shell and OS you are using for a better answer.